# Impulse response and z transform question?

Tags: transformation, signal-processing

We have $g(k)=\{ [(1/5)^k]u(k)\text{ for $1 \le k\le3$ and $0$ for other }k\}$

The input is $x(k)=\delta(k) +3\delta(k-1)+ \delta(k-2) $

Using Z transform  we have to find the output $y(k)$ and the region of convergence of $Y(z)$.

The problem is that  although I have read about the input and output and impulse in the Alan V. Oppenheim book about signals,I dont know how to solve this one,especially the part about finding the output.

Comment: By $d(k)$ do you mean the discrete delta impulse?

Comment: Yes thats what I mean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case using the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform seems almost like an overkill, but let's see. I use $a=1/5$:

$$G(z)=\sum_{k=0}^3a^kz^{-k}=\frac{1-(az^{-1})^4}{1-az^{-1}}\\
X(z)=1+3z^{-1}+z^{-2}$$

So we have

$$Y(z)=X(z)G(z)=G(z)+3G(z)z^{-1}+G(z)z^{-2}\tag{1}$$

Since $Y(z)$ has the same pole as $G(z)$ (which is $z_{\infty}=a$), its region of convergence is $|z|>|a|=1/5$. (Since $Y(z)$ corresponds to a causal sequence, the region of convergence is the region *outside* a circle).

The inverse transform of (1) is simply

$$y(k)=g(k)+3g(k-1)+g(k-2)$$

I'm sure you can fill in the numerical values yourself if necessary.

Comment: Since g(k) = $(1/5)d(k-1)$ + $(1/5)^2 d(k-2)$ + $(1/5)^3 d(k-3)$, then  $3g(k-1)$ is $(3/5)d(k-2)$ + $(3/5)^2 d(k-3)$ + $(3/5)^3 d(k-4)$ right?

Comment: @fsdd: Not exactly, because $3(1/5)^2$ is not equal to $(3/5)^2$, but the basic idea is correct.

Comment: Okay I will correct that,thank you.